# Error during template rendering in Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.6.1
I am trying to follow a Django tutorial on Openclassroom ([Tuto](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-django/les-vues-generiques?q=&hPP=8&idx=prod_v2_COURSES_fr&p=0&fR%5Bcertificate%5D%5B0%5D=true&fR%5BisWeb%5D%5B0%5D=true&is_v=1)), I have a problem that I can not solve, I can not remove this error

Here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\crepes\blog\views.py" in accueil
  15.     return render(request, 'blog/accueil.html', {'articles': articles})

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  458.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /blog/accueil
Exception Value: Reverse for 'blog_lire' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<slug>.+)$']
```

Some code :

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
  titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  auteur = models.CharField(max_length=42)
  contenu = models.TextField(null=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date de parution",
                            auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
  is_visible = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Article publié ?",
                                 default=False)
  categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.titre

class Categorie(models.Model):
  titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.titre
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Article

def accueil(request): 
  articles = Article.objects.filter(is_visible=True).order_by('-date')[:4]
  return render(request, 'blog/accueil.html', {'articles': articles})

def lire_article(request, slug):
   article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
   return render(request, 'blog/lire_article.html', {'article': article})
```

blog/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^accueil$', views.accueil),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)$', views.lire_article, name='blog_lire'),
  ]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  ]
```

accueil.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Accueil du blog{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Derniers articles</h1>

  {% for article in articles %}
    <h2 class="titre-article">{{ article.titre }}</h2>

    <p class="infos-article">Le {{ article.date|date:'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT' }}, XX commentaires.</p>

    <div class="contenu-article">
        {{ article.contenu|safe|truncatewords_html:30 }}
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'blog_lire' article.slug %}">Lire la suite</a></p>

    <hr />
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ article.titre }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <p>
      <a href="{% url 'accueil' %}">Retour à la liste des articles</a>
  </p>

  <h2 class="titre-article">{{ article.titre }}</h2>
  <p class="infos-article">Par {{ article.auteur }}, le {{ article.date }}</p>

  <div class="contenu-article">
    {{ article.contenu|safe }}
  </div>

  <h3 class="titre-comments">Commentaires</h3>

  <h4>Poster votre propre commentaire</h4>
  <form method="post" action="" class="pure-form">

     <!-- A vous de remplir le formulaire également -->

     <p style="text-align:center">
         <input class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type="submit" />
     </p>
   </form>

   <div class="clear"></div>


   <div class="commentaire">
     <p>Maxime, le 28 mai 2019</p>
     <p>Ceci est un exemple de commentaire, qui est à remplacer par votre modèle</p>
   </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show the accueil.html template, since the error is happening there.

Comment: its actually a url problem. Give a namespace to your main blog url and then include it on template as {% url 'your_blog_namespace':'blog_lire'  slug=yourslug %}

Comment: Aniket, sorry i'm begginer if you can give me more explanations plz !?

Comment: @Aniket no, the problem is not the namespace, otherwise it wouldn't try the blog_lire pattern at all; but as you can see from the error, it does say "1 pattern tried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of your articles has an empty slug.

The error shows that it is trying to find the correct URL to link to the "blog_lire" page for each article, using the slug. But it's failing, because it has an empty string for the slug, so it can't generate that link.

You should ensure that all your articles have a value for their slug field.

Comment: Yes ur right, i checked my DB and found that i have 2 articles with no value at Slug,
actually i want to remove these 2 articles from my DB
can u just help me how to do this in the Python shell, plz??

Comment: `Article.objects.filter(slug='').delete()`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
{% url 'blog_lire' article.slug %}"
```

try

```
{% url 'blog:blog_lire' slug=article.slug %}"
```

or something like that